# Mysql innodb reference integrity with an empty tablr

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

How an empty table can throw a "A foreign key constraint fails"?
I have two table: "listini" and "listinoprezzi", the second one has a foreign reference to the first one. However the "listinoprezzi" is empty, and when I try to truncate "listini" I get:

```
#1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`listiniprezzi`, CONSTRAINT `listiniprezzi_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`listino`) REFERENCES `listini` (`id`))
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [`TRUNCATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/truncate-table.html) (emphasis added):

> To achieve high performance, it bypasses the DML method of deleting data. Thus, it cannot be rolled back, it does not cause `ON DELETE` triggers to fire, and **it cannot be performed for `InnoDB` tables with parent-child foreign key relationships.**
>
> Although [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/truncate-table.html) is similar to [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html), it is classified as a DDL statement rather than a DML statement.  It differs from [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html) in the following ways in MySQL 5.5:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - **[`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/truncate-table.html) fails for an `InnoDB` table if there are any `FOREIGN KEY` constraints from other tables that reference the table.** Foreign key constraints between columns of the same table are permitted.

Comment: You can: drop the foreign key constraint first and then `TRUNCATE`; or just use `DELETE`.